# Dynamically Adding an MDL Text Input via JavaScript, not via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design-lite

Dynamically adding a text input via AJAX and using the `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` works well.
However, when I clone a text input using JavaScript alone, that function doesn't help.

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-amber.min.css">
  </head>
    <body>
        <div id="formElements">
            <div class="formElementGroup">
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                      <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Q1">Question</label><input type="text" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="Q1" name="Q1[]">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Qs1"></div>
            <div align="left">
              <a id="Btn-addQuestion" class="Btn-addQuestion">
                Add another text field
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formElements").on("click", ".Btn-addQuestion", function(){
              clonedTxtBox = $("#Q1").parents(".formElementGroup").clone(true);
              clonedTxtBox.appendTo("#Qs1");
              setTimeout(function(){
                componentHandler.upgradeDom();
              }, 1000);
            });
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect that the label of the cloned text input move upwards and become smaller as it is designed to behave. However, only the original one does-- the cloned one doesn't; it rather sticks over the text-input even if the user types something inside.

Any help would be appreciated.

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jp26f0ts/

Comment: `$("#formElements").on("click", ".Btn-addQuestion",` should do nothing since `.Btn-addQuestion` isn't a descendant of `#formElements`

Comment: You're right. I've just edited it.

Comment: When you clone your elements, you're also cloning their IDs, and IDs must be unique, which might be the real issue

Comment: I tried changing the id for the input as well as the "for" attr for the label after cloning, but it doesn't work. Here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gc4qzfxn/

Comment: Any new clue for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution somewhere online.
Before upgrading the DOM, I should have added this:

```
clonedTxtBox.find('.mdl-textfield').removeClass('is-upgraded').removeAttr('data-upgraded');
```